# white-space: nowrap; and flexbox did not work in chrome

Tags: css, overflow, flexbox, ellipsis, nowrap

Recent update of Chrome breaks `white-space: nowrap` using `text-overflow: ellipsis;` on a `overflow: hidden` element. How to fix that without adding hard-coded width on `name` class..

```
<h1>problem</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="name">
    <div class="firstname">
      test
    </div>
    <div class="lastname">
      as kjldashdk ja asdjhk ashdjk ashdjk asdjasdkajsdh akjsd asd asd asd asd asd asd as das da asdas dasd asda sdasd as dasd asd asd as dasd a
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="side">
    options
  </div>
</div>
```

The structure should not change because I reuse the `.name` section somewhere else in my app.

```
.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 10px;
}
.name {
  display: flex;
}
.firstname {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.lastname {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.side {
  flex-grow: 0;
}
.side, .firstname, .lastname {
  align-self: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZpMYg

Comment: I believe for `text-overflow: ellipsis` to work you must specify a `width` (or `flex-basis`), as well. That's what's missing in your `.lastname` class.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Reference - https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto

> The initial setting on flex items is `min-width: auto`. So, in order for
>   each item to stay within the container, we need to give `min-width: 0`.

Add  `min-width: 0;`. This is the easy workaround in your case.

that is

```
name {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 10px;
}
.name {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
}
.firstname {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.lastname {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
}
.side {
  flex-grow: 0;
}
.side, .firstname, .lastname {
  align-self: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>problem</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="name">
    <div class="firstname">
      test
    </div>
    <div class="lastname">
      as kjldashdk ja asdjhk ashdjk ashdjk asdjasdkajsdh akjsd asd asd asd asd asd asd as das da asdas dasd asda sdasd as dasd asd asd as dasd a
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="side">
    options
  </div>
</div>

<h1>expected result</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div class="name">
    <div class="firstname">
      test
    </div>
    <div class="lastname">
      as kjldashdk ja asdjhk ashdjk ashdjk asdjasdkajsdh akjsd asd asd asd asd sa dad...
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="side">
    options
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a nice article about the trick. https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/

Comment: from where you got `flex-items` are `min-width:auto` by default?

Answer (score 1):

Other variant for `text-overflow: ellipsis`
 when content `width` must be dynamic

```css
html, body{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }
  
body{
  padding-top: 10px
  }
  

.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  box-sizing: boder-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd
  }
  
.title{
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd
  }
  
.content{
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  overflow: hidden
  }
  
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis
  }

.area{
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex-grow: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ddd
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
      Title
  </div> 
  <div class="content">
    <div class="wrapper">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="area">
    Options
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
      Title
  </div> 
  <div class="content">
    <div class="wrapper"> Lorem_Ipsum_isssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="area">
    Options
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
      Title 1 | Title 2
  </div> 
  <div class="content">
    <div class="wrapper">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="area">
    Options 1 | Options 2
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
      Title 1 | Title 2
  </div> 
  <div class="content">
    <div class="wrapper"> Lorem_Ipsum_isssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="area">
    Options 1 | Options 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Example: https://codepen.io/Norfild/pen/KozJzg

Answer (score -1):

`text-overflow: ellipsis`  is work with the `width` property

```
.lastname { 
  width: 525px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```