# Text-overflow: ellipsis rendering problem on resize in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, ellipsis

Let's say I have badges or tags as `inline-block` elements inside some container and I want to use `text-overflow: ellipsis` to cut and add `...` at the end. Easy enough. Now let's try to resize the container on Chrome. If I write all HTML for badges in multiple lines - it's fine. If I write them in one line (like all frameworks/bundlers etc. will do nowadays) and start resizing - all dots are weirdly frozen in place.

Here's the demo: https://codepen.io/buszmen/pen/gOpKbVe

First one is in one line, second - multiple lines. Start resizing to see the effect.

This works fine on Firefox. 
I'd like to use a single line, cause otherwise it generates unwanted whitespace. I guess I can take this whitespace into account in CSS margins, but that sounds like a workaround not a solution.

Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Using `text-overflow: ellipsis` inside of an `display: flex` element in Chrome is common for errors. (See [question #34934586](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34934586/white-space-nowrap-and-flexbox-did-not-work-in-chrome) for example). I cannot find a workaround or a duplicate of that specific error. Maybe you ask this question on https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: I can reproduce it using tables without flex as well.

Comment: Ok, but still... search and report it on https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list if it's only appearing in Chrome/Chromium.They can probably help you more over there. Stack Overflow isn't the right place for your question.

Comment: Reported https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1062733

Comment: Can you still edit the report? You wrote it in the title, but `Steps to reproduce the problem:` is just a link. It is missing resizing of the window. Copying the title into this section should be enough. And you can add that it only appears on chrome and was reproduces by multiple Stack Overflow users.

Comment: I don't see any way to edit this unfortunately. I mentioned about resizing few times. I also noticed that it works on other browsers. And thanks for the support ;)

Comment: **Edit:** Nvm. I added a comment and a video. You already got 3 stars on your bug! Never saw that in 2 hours.

Comment: **Update:** This seemed to be a unique issue with Chromium which should now be [fixed in version 90](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1062733#c17) (or maybe even before that). Because of it's regression capability, an automated test for this bug in future versions is also in the pipeline.